# MySQL Query to insert a row to a table which doesn't have a specific value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which generates the below table of results,

```
select i.invoice_date,i.invoice_number,i.invoice_subtotal,p.payment from
invoice i
inner join payments p
on i.invoice_number = p.invoiceGRN_id
where i.payment_type = 'Credit'
```

[image]

What I need to do is,

- Insert a row for each invoice_number with the relevant
  invoice_subtotal(invoice_subtotal) which is same for a specific
  invoice_number,
- with the payment = 0.0 where if the particular invoice_number doesn't
  already have a record with payment = 0.0

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to insert in 2 tables (invoice and payments), you'll need a procedure with following 2 queries,

```
insert into invoice(invoice_date, invoice_number, invoice_subtotal,...) 
select invoice_date, invoice_number, invoice_subtotal,... from invoice i1 where i1.payment_type = 'Credit' and not exists(select * from payments p1 where i1.invoice_number = p1.invoiceGRN_id and p1.payment = 0.0);

insert into payments(invoiceGRN_id, payment, ...)
select invoiceGRN_id, payment,... from payments p1 where p1.invoiceGRN_id not in (select invoiceGRN_id from payments p2 where p2.payment=0.0);
```